# Which Ethereum accounts have the most Ether?

Tags: ether, accounts

Where can someone get a list of all the ethereum accounts and sort it by the # of ether they have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most convenient way to get his information presently is via etherscan blockchain explorer:

http://etherscan.io/accounts

Currently, it shows that top 5 accounts are:

**Poloniex Cold Wallet** (7.8 million Ether)

**Kraken** (2.2 million Ether)

**EthDev** (1.75 million - this is a multi signature contract)

**0x1937c5c515057553ccbd46d5866455ce66290284** (1 million Ether). This one has bought Ether at pre-sale and has not spent any of it yet

**0xd12cd8a37f074e7eafae618c986ff825666198bd** (almost 1 million Ether). This one accumulated it over the period of 170 days (withdrawn from Poloniex Hot Wallet)

Answer (score 4):

This is not accounting for people holding multiple accounts. Below is the first 3 pages of the list.

[image]
[image]
[image]